# Are there any Hubble images of Polymele available?

Tags: asteroids, hubble-telescope

Lucy is a spacecraft that will visit trojan asteroids, among which there is the asteroid Polymele. Before doing an occultation observing campaign for the asteroid Polymele in October 2021, the Lucy team used Hubble data to constrain the orbit of Polymele. Are the Hubble pictures of Polymele publicly available?

(I expect that you can't see much more than a couple pixels, but I'd still be curious to see the image)

Comment: It might help if you provided some background and references (e.g. what is "the Lucy team"?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HST Proposal 15144, entitled "Deep Search for Satellites Around the Lucy Mission Targets", has [a data page](https://archive.stsci.edu/proposal_search.php?id=15144&mission=hst) with 24 Hubble images of Polymele (you need to go to page 2 of 2 of the table). An example below:

[image]

There is also a publication ([Nole et al. 2020](https://doi.org/10.3847/PSJ/abac54)) associated with the proposal, but it focuses on Eurybates.

Comment: Is Polymele in the center of this image?

Comment: Yes it's the biggest/brigthest spot at the center.